# Ест ли разница между int a; int b; и int a, b; с точки зрения memory management?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

Я знаю, что int a; Int b; и int a, b; - то же самое. Но я хочу знать, может int a, b; использует меньше памяти во время компиляции, чем int a; Int b; . Есть ли разница между ними? Может компилятор будет работать быстрее ?

Comment: Никакой разницы.

Comment: "Может компилятор будет работать быстрее ?" - не экономьте на спичках.